# Get Tags specific to Category using WooCommerce plugin

Tags: categories, tags, plugins

Could anyone help me to implement this code in WooCommerce, ie instead of categories to use product categories, and instead of tag to use product tag.

In functions.php :

```
function get_category_tags($args) {
global $wpdb;
$tags = $wpdb->get_results
("
    SELECT DISTINCT terms2.term_id as tag_id, terms2.name as tag_name, null as tag_link
    FROM
        wp_posts as p1
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as r1 ON p1.ID = r1.object_ID
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as t1 ON r1.term_taxonomy_id = t1.term_taxonomy_id
        LEFT JOIN wp_terms as terms1 ON t1.term_id = terms1.term_id,

        wp_posts as p2
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as r2 ON p2.ID = r2.object_ID
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as t2 ON r2.term_taxonomy_id = t2.term_taxonomy_id
        LEFT JOIN wp_terms as terms2 ON t2.term_id = terms2.term_id
    WHERE
        t1.taxonomy = 'category' AND p1.post_status = 'publish' AND terms1.term_id IN (".$args['categories'].") AND
        t2.taxonomy = 'post_tag' AND p2.post_status = 'publish'
        AND p1.ID = p2.ID
    ORDER by tag_name
");
$count = 0;
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $tags[$count]->tag_link = get_tag_link($tag->tag_id);
    $count++;
}
return $tags;
}
```

In wp theme:

```
$args = array('categories'=> '3'); 
$tags = get_category_tags($args); 
$content .= "<ul>"; 
foreach ($tags as $tag) { 
    $content .= "<li><a href=\"$tag->tag_link\">$tag->tag_name</a></li>";
} 
$content .= "</ul>"; 
echo $content;
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally solve the problem:

```
t1.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND p1.post_status = 'publish' AND terms1.term_id IN (".$args['categories'].") AND
t2.taxonomy = 'product_tag' AND p2.post_status = 'publish'
```

---

In the functions.php

```
t1.taxonomy = 'category' AND p1.post_status = 'publish' AND terms1.term_id IN (".$args['categories'].") AND t2.taxonomy = 'post_tag' AND p2.post_status = 'publish'
```

rename `category` to `product_cat`, and `post_tag` with `product_tag`.

Comment: Can you post a bit more of the code or set up the code that solved your problem. I think this will be more helpful to other users.